# A tree like (graphviz) stack trace (Visualize debugging)

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, graphviz

I was trying to find if there exists a library or tool that will allow me to visually debug my program. i.e. something that shows a graphviz like tree structure and highlights exactly where I am in the process tree at a breakpoint. This would give a faster understanding of how my process works rather than sequentially debug through and create a tree in my mind.

I found something that partially does what I am looking for, i.e. show a tree structure of my process and the number of calls made per function call
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-graphvis/

If it doesn't exist then I might plan on writing something that does the job. Thanks

-CV

Answer (score 1):

The [debug visualization plugin for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/debug-visualisation-eclipse) sounds like something that might be helpful for you. Furthermore, the venerable [Data Display Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) also has some automatic routines for creating graphs, albeit of the data structures you are currently seeing. I also like the visualization of [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), but it is not exactly a *debugging* aid. However, its graphical view shows you the position in the execution tree.

Since there does not seem to be a tool that matches your requirements exactly, maybe these ones will inspire you to write your own ;)

Comment: I'll try the plugin and see. Right now, am a bit off track implementing a different project, this one is next on my list.